# How to display name instead of id if records are in one table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I have an employee table and records are

```
id |firstname | lastname | mobileno   | created_by
 2 |mnb       | nbgfv    | 1452145625 | 1
 3 |jhg       | uhgf     | 1452365478 | 2
 4 |poi       | ijuy     | 1458745632 | 2
 5 |tgf       | tgfd     | 1458745254 | 2
 6 |wer       | qwes     | 1523654512 | 2
```

Now My issue is in the column `created_by`. When I am displaying the record of any id value then I am getting the output like

```
    id |firstname | lastname | mobileno   | created_by
     3 |jhg       | uhgf     | 1452365478 | 2
```

But my expected output

```
id |firstname | lastname | mobileno   | created_by
 3 |jhg       | uhgf     | 1452365478 | mnb nbgfv
```

I have to display the name of `created_by`

I tried only this query.

```
   $get_single_emp_record = array('id' => 3);
   $this->db->where($get_single_emp_record);
   $query = $this->db->get('tbl_employee');
   $result = $query->row();
   if($result)
   {
   return $result;
   }
   else 
   {
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: I'm assuming the `created_by` is the `id` of another user, so join to the same table using this column.

Comment: @NigelRen, Yes, I have only one table and created_by is the id of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hint (maybe this can give solution in your problem).
Try query like this :

```
SELECT 
t1.id , t1.firstname , t1.lastname ,t1.mobileno, 
CONCAT(t2.firstname ," ",t2.lastname ) AS createby 
FROM tbl_employee AS t1 
JOIN tbl_employee AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.created_by
WHERE t1.id = '3'
```

With above query you no need create temporary table or other additional tables.
I Tested it. >>>
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e693cf/2/0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create another table maybe `tbl_creator` which will have the `id, creator_name` then in your query you will perform a Join operation

Comment: Any other way to display? because I don't want to create one more table. I have already more than 200 records in the table.

Comment: I believe thats the best way to go about it if you want to achieve your goal

Comment: Just two tables will do the magic employees table and creator table then perform a join